# The usage of the past tense of the word ‘assign’: ‘assigned’

Tags: meaning, grammar, tenses

I understand the meaning of the transitive verb assign, however, I had a question regarding the usage of the past tense of the word assign: assigned. Observe the following statement:

If “a is assigned to b, then b is assigned a.”

So, does “a is assigned to b” mean “b is assigned a”?

For example: is “the student (a) is assigned to an advisor (b)” equivalent to “the advisor (b) is assigned a student (a)”?

Please give an explanation as to why the word “assigned” may be used this way grammatically (or grammatically, if this comes down to a grammatical problem

Comment: I don't see there's anything to "explain" here, where *to assign A to B* doesn't really mean any more than ***to make a link between A and B***. And there's no reason we can't treat that as a "two-way" link, so it doesn't necessarily matter which order we present the "linked" elements.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - thank you very much. I must have just been over thinking it and wanted to be thorough!

Comment: It's technically correct, but I'd advise against using the phrase "B is assigned A", as it's likely to be misread/misheard as the more common "B is assigned to A".

Comment: @curiousdannii - absolutely. The reason I included the other phrase is because I am a mathematician and each phrase is important to my studies!

Comment: Try 'this wine drinks well' or 'the people were soon voted'. Be aware that different verbs behave differently, and expecting universal patterns is dooming oneself to disappointment.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I’ve read your answers before! Glad you made it to one of my questions. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - question: do you have to say first that a is assigned to b in order to say b is assigned a? Or does it not matter which you say first in order for the other to make sense?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - would you care to comment on my previous comment above this one addressed to the other user? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at the example sentences at [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/assign). eg << 'UN troops were assigned the task of rebuilding the hospital.' but note the categorisations here: 'to give a particular job or piece of work to someone' & [usages involving using two objects] >> Quite often, verb usages select certain semantic types of objects. Look at quite a few example sentences from various dictionaries. 'Professor Xavier was assigned Wolverine' sounds rather dismissive (and wouldn't have gone down too well).